# Сборка и использование библиотеки libharu (v2.3.0-RC3)

Tags: qt, pdf

Пытаюсь собрать и использовать библиотеку libharu (v2.3.0-RC3). Что использую: (Windows 7, Qt 5.9.1, Qt Creator 4.3.1, CMake 3.9.0 - rc5, GNU Make 3.82.90).

### Как это пытаюсь сделать:

- исходники были взяты [здесь](http://libharu.org/)
- распаковка "C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu"
- mkdir libharu_build
- cd libharu_build
- `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="C:\gnuwin32\include\" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="C:\gnuwin32\lib\" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\`

вывод в консоль

```
C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="C:\gnuwin32\include" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="C:\gnuwin32\lib\" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h
-- Looking for include file inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for include file memory.h
-- Looking for include file memory.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for include file unistd.h
-- Looking for include file unistd.h - found
-- Found ZLIB: C:/gnuwin32/lib/libz.dll.a (found version "1.2.3")
-- Found PNG: C:/gnuwin32/lib/libpng.dll.a (found version "1.2.37")
Summary of CMake build system results for the haru library
Install location variables which can be set by the user:
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:      C:/Program Files (x86)/libharu
CMAKE_INSTALL_EXEC_PREFIX
CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR
CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR
Other important CMake variables:
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:      Windows
UNIX:
WIN32:                  1
APPLE:
MSVC:                           (MSVC_VERSION:  )
MINGW:                  1
MSYS:
CYGWIN:
BORLAND:
WATCOM:
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:       Release
CMAKE_C_COMPILER CMAKE_C_FLAGS:                 C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Library options:
LIBHPDF_SHARED:         ON
LIBHPDF_STATIC:         ON
LIBHPDF_EXAMPLES:       OFF
DEVPAK:                 OFF
Optional libraries:
HAVE_LIBZ:              TRUE
HAVE_LIBPNG:            TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Qt/Projects/libharu/libharu/libharu_build
C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build>mingw32-make
Scanning dependencies of target hpdfs
[  0%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_annotation.obj
[  1%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_array.obj
[  2%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_binary.obj
[  3%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_boolean.obj
[  4%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_catalog.obj
[  5%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_destination.obj
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_dict.obj
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_doc_png.obj
[  7%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_doc.obj
[  8%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_cns.obj
[  9%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_cnt.obj
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_jp.obj
[ 11%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_kr.obj
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder.obj
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encrypt.obj
[ 13%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encryptdict.obj
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_error.obj
[ 15%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_ext_gstate.obj
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font_cid.obj
[ 17%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font_tt.obj
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font_type1.obj
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font.obj
[ 19%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_base14.obj
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cid.obj
[ 21%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cns.obj
[ 22%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cnt.obj
[ 23%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_jp.obj
[ 24%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_kr.obj
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_tt.obj
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_type1.obj
[ 26%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef.obj
[ 27%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_gstate.obj
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_image_ccitt.obj
[ 29%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_image_png.obj
[ 30%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_image.obj
[ 31%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_info.obj
[ 31%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_list.obj
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_mmgr.obj
[ 33%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_name.obj
[ 34%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_namedict.obj
[ 35%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_null.obj
[ 36%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_number.obj
[ 37%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_objects.obj
[ 37%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_outline.obj
[ 38%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_page_label.obj
[ 39%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_page_operator.obj
[ 40%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_pages.obj
[ 41%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_real.obj
[ 42%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_streams.obj
[ 43%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_string.obj
[ 43%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_u3d.obj
[ 44%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_utils.obj
[ 45%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_xref.obj
[ 46%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_pdfa.obj
[ 47%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_3dmeasure.obj
[ 48%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_exdata.obj
[ 49%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_utf.obj
[ 50%] Linking C static library libhpdfs.a
[ 50%] Built target hpdfs
Scanning dependencies of target hpdf
[ 50%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_annotation.obj
[ 51%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_array.obj
[ 52%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_binary.obj
[ 53%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_boolean.obj
[ 54%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_catalog.obj
[ 55%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_destination.obj
[ 56%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_dict.obj
[ 56%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_doc_png.obj
[ 57%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_doc.obj
[ 58%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_cns.obj
[ 59%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_cnt.obj
[ 60%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_jp.obj
[ 61%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_kr.obj
[ 62%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder.obj
[ 62%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encrypt.obj
[ 63%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encryptdict.obj
[ 64%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_error.obj
[ 65%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_ext_gstate.obj
[ 66%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font_cid.obj
[ 67%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font_tt.obj
[ 68%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font_type1.obj
[ 68%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font.obj
[ 69%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_base14.obj
[ 70%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cid.obj
[ 71%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cns.obj
[ 72%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cnt.obj
[ 73%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_jp.obj
[ 74%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_kr.obj
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_tt.obj
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_type1.obj
[ 76%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef.obj
[ 77%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_gstate.obj
[ 78%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_image_ccitt.obj
[ 79%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_image_png.obj
[ 80%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_image.obj
[ 81%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_info.obj
[ 81%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_list.obj
[ 82%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_mmgr.obj
[ 83%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_name.obj
[ 84%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_namedict.obj
[ 85%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_null.obj
[ 86%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_number.obj
[ 87%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_objects.obj
[ 87%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_outline.obj
[ 88%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_page_label.obj
[ 89%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_page_operator.obj
[ 90%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_pages.obj
[ 91%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_real.obj
[ 92%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_streams.obj
[ 93%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_string.obj
[ 93%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_u3d.obj
[ 94%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_utils.obj
[ 95%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_xref.obj
[ 96%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_pdfa.obj
[ 97%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_3dmeasure.obj
[ 98%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_exdata.obj
[ 99%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_utf.obj
[100%] Linking C shared library libhpdf.dll
[100%] Built target hpdf
```

- mingw32-make

вывод в консоль

```
C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build>mingw32-make
Scanning dependencies of target hpdfs
[  0%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_annotation.obj
[  1%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_array.obj
[  2%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_binary.obj
[  3%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_boolean.obj
[  4%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_catalog.obj
[  5%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_destination.obj
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_dict.obj
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_doc_png.obj
[  7%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_doc.obj
[  8%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_cns.obj
[  9%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_cnt.obj
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_jp.obj
[ 11%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_kr.obj
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder.obj
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encrypt.obj
[ 13%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encryptdict.obj
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_error.obj
[ 15%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_ext_gstate.obj
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font_cid.obj
[ 17%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font_tt.obj
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font_type1.obj
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_font.obj
[ 19%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_base14.obj
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cid.obj
[ 21%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cns.obj
[ 22%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cnt.obj
[ 23%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_jp.obj
[ 24%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_kr.obj
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_tt.obj
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef_type1.obj
[ 26%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_fontdef.obj
[ 27%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_gstate.obj
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_image_ccitt.obj
[ 29%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_image_png.obj
[ 30%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_image.obj
[ 31%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_info.obj
[ 31%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_list.obj
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_mmgr.obj
[ 33%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_name.obj
[ 34%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_namedict.obj
[ 35%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_null.obj
[ 36%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_number.obj
[ 37%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_objects.obj
[ 37%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_outline.obj
[ 38%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_page_label.obj
[ 39%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_page_operator.obj
[ 40%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_pages.obj
[ 41%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_real.obj
[ 42%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_streams.obj
[ 43%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_string.obj
[ 43%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_u3d.obj
[ 44%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_utils.obj
[ 45%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_xref.obj
[ 46%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_pdfa.obj
[ 47%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_3dmeasure.obj
[ 48%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_exdata.obj
[ 49%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdfs.dir/hpdf_encoder_utf.obj
[ 50%] Linking C static library libhpdfs.a
[ 50%] Built target hpdfs
Scanning dependencies of target hpdf
[ 50%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_annotation.obj
[ 51%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_array.obj
[ 52%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_binary.obj
[ 53%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_boolean.obj
[ 54%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_catalog.obj
[ 55%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_destination.obj
[ 56%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_dict.obj
[ 56%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_doc_png.obj
[ 57%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_doc.obj
[ 58%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_cns.obj
[ 59%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_cnt.obj
[ 60%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_jp.obj
[ 61%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_kr.obj
[ 62%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder.obj
[ 62%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encrypt.obj
[ 63%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encryptdict.obj
[ 64%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_error.obj
[ 65%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_ext_gstate.obj
[ 66%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font_cid.obj
[ 67%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font_tt.obj
[ 68%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font_type1.obj
[ 68%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_font.obj
[ 69%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_base14.obj
[ 70%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cid.obj
[ 71%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cns.obj
[ 72%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_cnt.obj
[ 73%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_jp.obj
[ 74%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_kr.obj
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_tt.obj
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef_type1.obj
[ 76%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_fontdef.obj
[ 77%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_gstate.obj
[ 78%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_image_ccitt.obj
[ 79%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_image_png.obj
[ 80%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_image.obj
[ 81%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_info.obj
[ 81%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_list.obj
[ 82%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_mmgr.obj
[ 83%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_name.obj
[ 84%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_namedict.obj
[ 85%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_null.obj
[ 86%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_number.obj
[ 87%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_objects.obj
[ 87%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_outline.obj
[ 88%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_page_label.obj
[ 89%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_page_operator.obj
[ 90%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_pages.obj
[ 91%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_real.obj
[ 92%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_streams.obj
[ 93%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_string.obj
[ 93%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_u3d.obj
[ 94%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_utils.obj
[ 95%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_xref.obj
[ 96%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_pdfa.obj
[ 97%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_3dmeasure.obj
[ 98%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_exdata.obj
[ 99%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/hpdf.dir/hpdf_encoder_utf.obj
[100%] Linking C shared library libhpdf.dll
[100%] Built target hpdf
```

- в результате получаю нужные файлы `"C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build\src\libhpdf.dll"-"C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build\include\hpdf_config.h"`

содержимое директории src

```
C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build\src>dir

11.07.2017  11:30    <DIR>          .
11.07.2017  11:30    <DIR>          ..
11.07.2017  11:29    <DIR>          CMakeFiles
11.07.2017  11:29             2 585 cmake_install.cmake
11.07.2017  11:30           815 942 libhpdf.dll
11.07.2017  11:30           194 034 libhpdf.dll.a
11.07.2017  11:30           929 178 libhpdfs.a
11.07.2017  11:29            76 899 Makefile
```

- в файле (.pro) проекта: `INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\include \
                 C:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build\include
  LIBS += -LC:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build\src -lhpdf`

содержимое main файла

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <hpdf.h>

jmp_buf env;

#ifdef HPDF_DLL
void  __stdcall
#else
void
#endif
error_handler (HPDF_STATUS   error_no,
               HPDF_STATUS   detail_no,
               void         *user_data)
{
    printf ("ERROR: error_no=%04X, detail_no=%u\n", (HPDF_UINT)error_no,
                (HPDF_UINT)detail_no);
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

const char *font_list[] = {
    "Courier",
    "Courier-Bold",
    "Courier-Oblique",
    "Courier-BoldOblique",
    "Helvetica",
    "Helvetica-Bold",
    "Helvetica-Oblique",
    "Helvetica-BoldOblique",
    "Times-Roman",
    "Times-Bold",
    "Times-Italic",
    "Times-BoldItalic",
    "Symbol",
    "ZapfDingbats",
    NULL
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    const char *page_title = "Font Demo";
    HPDF_Doc  pdf;
    char fname[256];
    HPDF_Page page;
    HPDF_Font def_font;
    HPDF_REAL tw;
    HPDF_REAL height;
    HPDF_REAL width;
    HPDF_UINT i;

    strcpy (fname, argv[0]);
    strcat (fname, ".pdf");

    pdf = HPDF_New (error_handler, NULL);
    if (!pdf) {
        printf ("error: cannot create PdfDoc object\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (setjmp(env)) {
        HPDF_Free (pdf);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Add a new page object. */
    page = HPDF_AddPage (pdf);

    height = HPDF_Page_GetHeight (page);
    width = HPDF_Page_GetWidth (page);

    /* Print the lines of the page. */
    HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth (page, 1);
    HPDF_Page_Rectangle (page, 50, 50, width - 100, height - 110);
    HPDF_Page_Stroke (page);

    /* Print the title of the page (with positioning center). */
    def_font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, "Helvetica", NULL);
    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, def_font, 24);

    tw = HPDF_Page_TextWidth (page, page_title);
    HPDF_Page_BeginText (page);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, (width - tw) / 2, height - 50, page_title);
    HPDF_Page_EndText (page);

    /* output subtitle. */
    HPDF_Page_BeginText (page);
    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, def_font, 16);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, 60, height - 80, "<Standerd Type1 fonts samples>");
    HPDF_Page_EndText (page);

    HPDF_Page_BeginText (page);
    HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos (page, 60, height - 105);

    i = 0;
    while (font_list[i]) {
        const char* samp_text = "abcdefgABCDEFG12345!#$%&+-@?";
        HPDF_Font font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, font_list[i], NULL);

        /* print a label of text */
        HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, def_font, 9);
        HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, font_list[i]);
        HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos (page, 0, -18);

        /* print a sample text. */
        HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, font, 20);
        HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, samp_text);
        HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos (page, 0, -20);

        i++;
    }

    HPDF_Page_EndText (page);

    HPDF_SaveToFile (pdf, fname);

    /* clean up */
    HPDF_Free (pdf);
    return a.exec();
}
```

содержимое hpdf_config.h файла

```
/* include/hpdf_config.h.in.  Generated from configure.in by autoheader.  */

/* Define to 1 if you have the <dlfcn.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_DLFCN_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <inttypes.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_INTTYPES_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the `png' library (-lpng). */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_LIBPNG

/* Define to 1 if you have the `z' library (-lz). */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_LIBZ

/* Define to 1 if you have the <memory.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_MEMORY_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <stdint.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_STDINT_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <stdlib.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_STDLIB_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <strings.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_STRINGS_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <string.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_STRING_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/stat.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_SYS_STAT_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/types.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H

/* Define to 1 if you have the <unistd.h> header file. */
#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_UNISTD_H

/* debug build */
/* #undef LIBHPDF_DEBUG */

/* debug trace enabled */
/* #undef LIBHPDF_DEBUG_TRACE */

/* libpng is not available */
/* #undef LIBHPDF_HAVE_NOPNGLIB */
/* #undef HPDF_NOPNGLIB */

/* zlib is not available */
/* #undef LIBHPDF_HAVE_NOZLIB */

/* Define to the address where bug reports for this package should be sent. */
#define LIBHPDF_PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "TODO"

/* Define to the full name of this package. */
#define LIBHPDF_PACKAGE_NAME "libHaru-2.2.0-gcc"

/* Define to the full name and version of this package. */
#define LIBHPDF_PACKAGE_STRING "libHaru-2.2.0-gcc"

/* Define to the one symbol short name of this package. */
#define LIBHPDF_PACKAGE_TARNAME "TODO"

/* Define to the version of this package. */
#define LIBHPDF_PACKAGE_VERSION "2.2.0"

/* Define to 1 if you have the ANSI C header files. */
#define LIBHPDF_STDC_HEADERS

/* Define to `unsigned int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
/* #undef LIBHPDF_size_t */
```

- при запуске проекта

получаю подобные сообщения

```
D:\..\..\..\main.cpp:58: ошибка: undefined reference to `HPDF_New'
D:\..\..\..\main.cpp:65: ошибка: undefined reference to `HPDF_Free'
D:\..\..\..\main.cpp:70: ошибка: undefined reference to `HPDF_AddPage'
```

- если в файле hpdf.h

сделать так

```
//#ifdef HPDF_DLL_MAKE
#    define HPDF_EXPORT(A)  __declspec(dllexport) A  __stdcall
//#else
//#    ifdef HPDF_DLL_MAKE_CDECL
//#        define HPDF_EXPORT(A)  __declspec(dllexport) A
//#    else
//#        ifdef HPDF_SHARED_MAKE
//#            define HPDF_EXPORT(A)  extern A
//#        endif /* HPDF_SHARED_MAKE */
//#    endif /* HPDF_DLL_MAKE_CDECL */
//#endif /* HPDF_DLL_MAKE */
```

то проект собирается без ошибок, но функционал не работает. Подскажите как заставить работать сию библу, буду признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было в файле (.pro) изменить подключение библиотек на:

```
LIBS += -LC:\Qt\Projects\libharu\libharu\libharu_build\src\ -lhpdfs
LIBS += -LC:\gnuwin32\lib\ -lz
```